# How do I render plain object as JSON, XML in Grails?

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I have a controller (`RestfulController`) code similar to the following:

```
def doSomethingAwesome() {
    Domain domainObject = prepareDomainObject()
    //do something on the domain object
    Model model = new Model(name: domainObject.name, description: domainObject.description)
    respond model
}
```

As can be seen, I'm trying to respond with data wrapped inside a `Model` object. However, `Model` class is not a domain class; it's just a plain Groovy class. When I try to test this code in isolation, I get it to pass, but when I test it with all the other tests, I get `GroovyCastException` saying the object cannot be cast to JSON.

Some of the articles that came up of my searches suggest I put the model object inside a map then have that map get rendered. Something like:

```
render ['model': model] as JSON
```

However, this isn't how I'd like the response message to be. In addition, the XML message would look very different.

Comment: Isnt it simply `render model as JSON`? How does the resonse currently look like, how do you want it to look like?

Comment: Rendering as JSON doesn't work as well because I think internally that's what `respond` basically does. Model is just a plain Groovy class. You can think that `name`, and `description` above are all the properties it has. I want the response to look like how model objects are usually rendered without external container object wrapping it inside.

Comment: render(contentType: "application/json") {
    book(title: b.title, author: b.author)

from here: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Controllers/render.html maybe this will help You?

Comment: why do you need a `Model` POGO here? a simple hash would do

Comment: There are reasons for doing it this way, and I think they're pretty sound. The `Model` class can be from other module/jar for example. I also can't use map because that doesn't translate well in XML.

Answer (score 0):

The Grails 2.4.3 demo project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/pogorespond demonstrates passing a POGO (not a domain class) to the `respond` method.  https://github.com/jeffbrown/pogorespond/blob/1646c64fe2b37856fc87b64ae1cf5a6c4fd44cb1/grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy contains the following:

```
package demo

class DemoController {

    static responseFormats = ['json']

    def index() {
        def m = new Model(name: 'Some Name', description: 'Some Description')
        respond m
    }
}

class Model {
    String name
    String description
}
```

Comment: That example only includes `json` in the `responseFormats` but of course you can use whatever you want to support.  You can leave that out altogether if you like.  If you send requests with Accept headers indicating you want "application/json" or "application/xml" (for example), it still works.

Comment: I'm still using 2.3.11 because I think 2.4.x requires Java 7 (which I'm still on the fence about upgrading to). Is the POGO rendering only available on 2.4.3? Also I noticed the controller doesn't extend `RestfulController` anymore. If I understand correctly, `responseFormats` only gets used by `RestfulController` subclasses. Did this change in 2.4.x, or I just misunderstood it?

Comment: "I think 2.4.x requires Java 7" - I don't think that is correct.

Comment: "If I understand correctly, responseFormats only gets used by RestfulController subclasses." - That is incorrect.

Comment: I just pushed a change to that repo which downgrades the app to Grails 2.3.11.

Comment: If you can identify whatever it takes to make that app throw the `GroovyCastException` that you are experiencing, please let me know and we will take a look.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I've been trying to replicate the problem using your demo but I can't make it to happen in there. I ended up creating a new project and moving my code step by step (using tests), and the problem is gone. I'm now using 2.4.3. As for it requiring Java 7, well, yeah it doesn't, but Grails keep warning me about `groovy-all` every time a make it do something. Is there a way to hide those without upgrading to Java 7?

Comment: "but Grails keep warning me about groovy-all" - That does not sound familiar.  I can't think of any place where we issue issue any warnings about groovy-all.  What is the warning message?

Comment: `WARNING: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]`. According to the results of my searches, it has something to do with using Java earlier than 7. It's actually becoming an eyesore, and it even led me to believe the latest version requires Java 7 to work properly.

Comment: That makes sense.  In any case, the project I linked above and the code posted in the answer above represent the way to do what you are asking with either Grails 2.3.11 or 2.4.x.  I hope that helps.

Comment: By the way, there's a mention of the `as` operator not being overloaded for POGO's in [this article](http://manbuildswebsite.com/2010/02/08/rendering-json-in-grails-part-2-plain-old-groovy-objects-and-domain-objects/). It's quite old, but it says the error I got was expected.

Comment: I am sorry that I wasn't able to help you out.  Best of luck.